# How to handle boolean attributes with groovy templates?

Tags: spring-mvc, groovy

Given the following groovy template element:

```
select(class: 'form-control input-sm',
       disabled: isDisabled)
```

I just wan't to disable the select if isDisabled is true. The problem is that HTML considers the presence of disabled as enough to disable the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem, I have no better idea than to simply do something like this:

```
isDisabled ? select(class: 'form-control input-sm', disabled:'disabled') : select(class: 'form-control input-sm')
```

**[updated]** or this:

```
def selectAttrs = [class: 'form-control input-sm']
if (isDisabled) selectAttrs += [disabled:'disabled']
select(selectAttrs)
```

Full test script:

```
import groovy.text.markup.MarkupTemplateEngine
import groovy.text.markup.TemplateConfiguration

model = [isDisabled:true]

def config = new TemplateConfiguration()
MarkupTemplateEngine engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config)
def template = engine.createTemplate '''
html {
body {
      isDisabled ? select(class: 'form-control input-sm', disabled:'disabled') : select(class: 'form-control input-sm')

      def selectAttrs = [class: 'form-control input-sm']
      if (isDisabled) selectAttrs += [disabled:'disabled']
      select(selectAttrs)
}
}
'''

StringWriter rendered = new StringWriter()
template.make(model).writeTo(rendered)

print rendered
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Groovy templates, but is it something you could use with a ternary expression? Possibly changing the expression to:

```
select(class: 'form-control input-sm' ${isDisabled?", disabled":""})
```

This would only include the `disabled` attribute if `isDisabled` is true.

Comment: Groovy templates are plain old groovy scripts (at least as far as my understanding goes), but they use a very nifty groovy builders API to make they look similar to some popular templating engines like Jade. So in OP's example we can see a call to a method named `select`, passing a map with two key-value pairs as a parameter. Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/hhSBJxcL), basically. Your proposed solution is not a valid groovy, unfortunately.